# Create multiple UILocalNotifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to create a new UILocalNotification every time I enter a certain method. I would assume this would have to be done by reading from an array or something along this line but I cannot figure it out. How do I do such a thing dynamically without hardcoding something like the following:

```
-(void) createNotification
 {
 UILocalNotification *notification1;
 }
```

Now I would like to be able to create notification2, notification3, etc etc each time I enter createNotification. For the specific reason that then I can cancel the appropriate notification without cancelling them all.

The following is what I have attempted, perhaps Im way off... maybe not. Either way if someone could provide some input, would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
-(void) AddNewNotification
{

UILocalNotification *newNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
//[notificationArray addObject:newNotification withKey:@"notificationN"];
notificationArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[notificationArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                   initWithObjectsAndKeys:newNotification,@"theNotification",nil]];

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there: using an array is certainly the right thing to do! The only problem is that you keep creating a new instance of the array every time you go through your `AddNewNotification` method. You should make `notificationArray` an instance variable, and move its initialization code `notificationArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` to the designated initializer of the class where `notificationArray` is declared.

If you would like to give each notification that you insert an individual key by which you can find it later, use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSMutableArray`. Re-write the `AddNewNotification` method as follows:

```
-(void) addNewNotificationWithKey:(NSString*)key {
    UILocalNotification *newNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [notificationDict setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
               initWithObjectsAndKeys:newNotification,@"theNotification",nil]
        forKey:key];

}
```

When you call the `addNewNotificationWithKey:` method, you'd be able to provide a key for the newly added notification, for example

```
[self addNewNotificationWithKey:@"notification1"];
[self addNewNotificationWithKey:@"notification2"];
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, excellent point. Something like viewDidLoad should do the trick for alloc? As for the rest of the code, so your saying I will be able to create newNotification1, newNotification2 by doing what I have done already? How is that possible if I am hard coding the name of the UILocalNotification variable as just "newNotification"? Won't it always be called that? Thanks and sorry if this is super easy... just getting a little confused

Comment: @AlexG You can do the initialization in the `viewDidLoad`, but the designated initializer is usually a better place for it. The name of the notification *variable* in the method that inserts the notification into the array does not matter at all: once the method is compiled, the name of the variable is gone! The array of notifications will contain all items that you have inserted into it. You will be able to iterate over them as needed, remove the items that are no longer needed, and so on.

Comment: ahh you are right that makes sense. One last question, I will accept your answer anyway but doesn't this cause a problem if I want to cancel a notification outside of these methods. Like cancel notification1 and notification2 but not notification3?

Comment: @AlexG You need a method to cancel notifications. There are several ways of going about the implementation: you could go through the array and find the notification by some of its attributes, say, the notification body, or you can use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSMutableArray`, and give each notification a "name". I'll update the answer to give you an example of using `NSMutableDictionary` in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much. The example would be great. Thanks again, will accept

Comment: Sorry but I just had a chance to test the edited code but I keep getting the following warning: addObject:withKey not found. I declared notificationDict as mutuabledictionary in my header file. Any ideas? thanks again

Comment: @AlexG Oops, the method name is 'setObject:forKey', I edited the answer.